# Kafka Stream vs Apache Storm?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm, real-time-data

I know how Kafka can be used as a message queue and can also be connected to Storm for real time data processing, I want to know Is there any advantage of using Kafka stream api over storm ?

Comment: depends on task - please reformulate the question with more specific details

Comment: Agree, It depends on task. My query is to know if am using Storm for real-time data processing and looking for similar framework for a better performance. So can i go with Apache streaming (if it has any adv) ?

Comment: Without knowledge about your particular task it's impossible to say - do you plan to do simple data transformations, or very complex aggregations, etc.?

Comment: it's a simple data processing (may be moderate you can say), not any complex aggregation.

Comment: Then Kafka streams could be simpler solution than Storm